# Caesar bruit force encryption

Tags: python

I'm having issues with the bruit force encryption within my python code.
For some reason the code breaks after the variable offset3 reaches 31 when I run the code and type "secret squirrel" into the variable brutef from the function option3.

In the requirements it has to be used with the ASCII from 32 to 126 utilising the "chr" and "ord" commands.

Is there something wrong with the code that is making it crash or is it just the way that I have wrote it.

```
def get_menu_choice():
    print('\n*** Menu ***\n')
    print('1. Encrupt string')
    print('2. Decrypt string')
    print('3. Brute force decryption')
    print('4. quit\n')
    option = int(input('What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]?'))
    while option not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        option = int(input('Invalid choice, please enter either 1, 2, 3 or 4:'))
    return option

def get_offset():
    offset = int(input('Please enter offset value (1 to 94): '))
    return offset

def option1():
    output1 = ''
    encrupt = input('\nPlease enter string to encrypt: ')
    offset = get_offset()
    for x in encrupt:
        if (ord(x) + offset > 126):
            letter = (ord(x) + offset) - 95
            output1 = output1 + chr(letter)
        else:
            letter = ord(x) + offset
            output1 = output1 + chr(letter)         
    print('\nEncrypted string:\n', output1)

def option2():
    output2 = ''
    decrypt = input('\nPlease enter string to decrypt: ')
    offset = get_offset()
    for y in decrypt:
        if (ord(y) - offset > 126):
            letter = (ord(y) - offset) - 95
            output2 = output2 + chr(letter)
        else:
            letter = ord(y) - offset
            output2 = output2 + chr(letter) 
    print('\nDecrypted string:\n', output2)

def option3():
    output3 = ''
    brutef = input('\nPlease enter string to decrypt: ')
    print()
    for offset3 in range(0,95):
        for z in brutef:               
            if (ord(z) - offset3 < 126):
                letter = ord(z) - offset3
                output3 = output3 + chr(letter)           
            if (ord(z) - offset3 > 126):
                letter = (ord(z) + offset3) - 95
                output3 = output3 + chr(letter)
        print('Offset:', offset3, '= Decrypted string:', output3 )                
        output3 =''

def option4():
    print('\nGoodbye',)


run = 'y'
while run == 'y':
    option = get_menu_choice()
    if option == 1:
        option1()
    elif option == 2:
        option2()
    elif option == 3:
        option3()
    elif option == 4:
        option4()
        run = 'n'
```

Comment: not all possible int values can be converted back to an character, what would you like to happen in this case? That character cannot be printed. You can ignore it if you want to.

Comment: the code needs to work as per these instructions: Your program must work with the printable ASCII character set. That is, all the characters from ASCII 32 (Space) to ASCII 126 (~). When the offset points to a character beyond 126 it should wrap around to the beginning of the set.

Comment: For example:

If the offset is 4 and character is ‘}’ (ASCII 125) then it will encrypt to ASCII 129. This is beyond 126 so wrap back to the beginning by subtracting the total number of characters (95). This gives character 34. Similarly, when decrypting, if the subtracted offset results in a number less than 32 then add 95 to the result.

Comment: That's not how your decrypt function works right now... I recommend creating a `decrypt` function that decrypts a given string and offset and _returns_ the decrypted string. Note that decrypt and encrypt are the same, only the sign of the offset differs in Caesar ciphers. Once you have this function working, creating the brute force function will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are doing the brute force search, some letter values might be *outside* the valid range of input values for `chr`, e.g. there is no valid character for that value.

The easiest way is to just ignore any invalid "letter values".

```
def option3():
    output3 = ''
    brutef = input('\nPlease enter string to decrypt: ')
    print()
    for offset3 in range(0,95):
        for z in brutef:               
            if (ord(z) - offset3 < 126):
                letter = ord(z) - offset3
                if letter in range(0, 0x10FFFF):
                    output3 = output3 + chr(letter)

            if (ord(z) - offset3 > 126):
                letter = (ord(z) + offset3) - 95
                if letter in range(0, 0x10FFFF):
                    output3 = output3 + chr(letter)
        print('Offset:', offset3, '= Decrypted string:', output3 )                
        output3 =''
```

You might want to clean this up to avoid any duplicated code.